# How to get option groups with a selectize control in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

A [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) control supports `optgroup` functionality, as demonstrated:

[image]

That is, in the above, "Climbing" is just a heading rather than a selectable option.

In R Shiny, this is selectize controls are produced using `selectizeInput`. But how can you achieve option groups with a `selectizeInput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open issue and will probably be fixed soon

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/326

> perhaps choices in selectInput() can also take a list of character
>   vectors to generate , e.g. choices = list(Eastern = c('NY',
>   'MA'), Western = c('CA', 'WA'))

Comment: This is what I see when I run that script:

[![screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Caoha.png